# Finding a subspace of $R^2$ which has uncountable many components and each of the components is uncountable

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

I am studying Topology from "An Illustrated Introduction to Topology and Homotopy" by Sasho Kalajdzievski. The author asks to find a subspace of $\mathbb R ^2$ with uncountably many components, all of them uncountable.

Here's my attempt:
Consider $\mathbb R \setminus \mathbb Q \times \mathbb R$. Since $\mathbb R \setminus \mathbb Q$ is uncountable and lines are uncountable, we will be done if we show that each of the component is of the form $x\times\mathbb R$ for some $x\in \mathbb R\setminus \mathbb Q$.

Let $C$ be a component of $\mathbb R \setminus \mathbb Q$ and suppose that $(x,y)\in C$. Then since $x\times \mathbb R$ is connected, $x\times \mathbb R\subseteq C$. Now the proof will be complete if I show that $C\subseteq x\times\mathbb R$.

Let $(x',y')\in C$. Then there must be a connected set $A$ of $\mathbb R\setminus \mathbb Q \times \mathbb R$ such that $(x',y'), (x,y) \in A$.

I will be done if I show that $x'=x$ but I have been unable to do so. Hints will be appreciated.

Other examples which satisfy the property are also welcome!

Comment: If $x \neq x'$ then there is a rational in between...

Comment: between needs a order?

Comment: the usual order of $\mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WLOG assume $x < x'$ and let $q \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $x < q < x'$, consider the open sets of $\mathbb{R}^2$: $U = \{(a, b): a < q \}$ and $V = \{(a, b): a > q \}$, the intersection of $U$ and $V$ with your space give you two open sets (disjoint and whose union is the whole space) that separate $(x, y)$ and $(x', y')$ and hence they can't be in the same connected component.